# Задача на вычисление суммы по вкладу

Tags: pascal

задача: в сберегательный банк был сделан вклад S рублей из расчета N% годовых. Какую сумму получит вкладчик через N лет?
вот что я нарешал, только тут еще ветвления с ифом не оформлены в двух местах,но там я справлюсь:

```
program e1_9;
var
p, s, i: real;
n, k : integer;

begin
  p:=(s+(s*i*n)/(k*100));
  writeln('vklad');
  readln(s);
  writeln('% stavka');
  readln(i);

  writeln('kolichestvo dney v gody');
  readln(k);

  writeln('kolichestvo dney nachislenia % po vkladu');
  readln(n);
  readln;
end.
```

но он не хочет выполняться дальше проверки переменных, пишет error 207:invalid floating point operation, пробовал менять типы переменных - переходит на строку формулы и пишет
error 26: Type mismatch.
кто знает в чем проблема,подскажите, пожалуйста, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Формула

```
 p:=(s+(s/n)/(k*100));
```

выполняется, когда переменные не проинициализированы и может произойти любая фигня с арифметикой (например, деление на ноль).

Эту формулу нужно выполнять после чтения переменных s, n и k.